# Prove that $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$ by using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that for integers $n > 0$, $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$.

Here is what I have done:

Base Step: $n=1$, $1^3+5(1)=6$

Inductive Step:

$p(k)=k^3 + 5k =6m$, $m$ is some integer

$p(k+1)=(k+1)^3+5(k+1)=6m$ $m$ is some integer

Since both are equal to $6m$ I set them equal to each other.

$k^3 + 5k=(k+1)^3+5(k+1)$

$k^3+5k=(k+1)[(k+1)^2+5]$

Proven that $p(k)=p(k+1)$

I do not think this is the correct way of proving this problem but I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: You want to expand $(k+1)^3+5(k+1)$ and then use that $k^3+5k=6m$ to show that $(k+1)^3+5(k+1)=6n$ for some integer n.

Comment: When I expand, I get $6m+3k^2 +3k +6$. How would I use that to show  $(k+1)^3+5(k+1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(k+1)^3+5(k+1) = (k^3 + 5k) + 3k^2 + 3k + 6$

Since $(k^3 + 5k)$ is divisible by 6, all you have to prove is $3k^2 + 3k + 6$ is divisible by 6 too. Since adding $6$ does not change divisibility, you just have to proove $3k(k+1)$ is divisible by 6. Think about even and odd numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out.